# iFrame Transparency

Tags: html, iframe

How is it possible to lay an iFrame that has a black background and is slightly transparent on top of a html page so it kinda darkens the page.

I have this so far and its not working.

```
<iframe id="fade" src="fade.html" frameborder="No" style="FILTER: chroma(color=#000000)" allowtransparency="true">  
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

fade.html

```
<html>
<body style="background:transparent">
</html>
```

Comment: Are you doing this just do create a mask over some elements? If so, you might consider just using a translucent `<div>` instead.

Comment: I am trying to do that. Ill take a look into that.

Comment: I'm still working on it but im not sure div will work. im trying to do something like looking at facebook pictures

Comment: The filter property seems a little bit too much to me, given it's browser support... Why don't you use a transparent black background color `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` and make the iframe fill width and height of the window using percentages.

Comment: @EricSauer Something like a lightbox (http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to place a translucent box over some elements, try positioning a `div` with the right `z-index` and [`opacity`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) properties:

HTML

```
​<p>I sit in the background and get covered up by a box.</p>
<div id="shade"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS

```
​#shade {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;  
}
```

[See an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjyXM/).

Comment: +1 i removed z-index from both p and shade css and still works on FireFox what its used for

Comment: @shareef The z-index determines what position something should be layered in the "stack". If you have several divs that you want covering up one another, you can use the `z-index` to make sure they're covering each other in the right order. It looks like my example was a little off--if you give the `p` tag a `z-index` higher than the `#shade` and a `position:absolute`, it will sit atop it.  Try playing with the z-indices in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WM5g9/1/